# How to split dataframe across tabs and apply crosstalk filters to all tabs in flexdashboard

Tags: r, split, tabs, leaflet, flexdashboard

I am trying to find a way to split my data into multiple tabs based on a column in the df (analyte) and apply the same filtering ability across all tabs. Below is an example of the figure and filter I'd like to generate with the figure column containing the multiple tabs.

````
Column {.tabset}
-------------------------------------

color_palette <- "viridis"
pal <- colorNumeric(palette = color_palette,
                    domain = map_df$meas_value)

s_df <- SharedData$new(map_df)

s_df %>%
# map_df %>%
  leaflet() %>%
  # addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "OpenStreetMap", 
                   group = "Open Street Map") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldStreetMap", 
                   group = "Esri World Street Map") %>%
  addProviderTiles(provider = "Esri.WorldImagery", 
                   group = "Esri World Imagery") %>%
  addCircles(color = ~pal(meas_value),
             fill = ~pal(meas_value),
             lng = ~lon,
             lat = ~lat,
             label = ~lapply(labs, htmltools::HTML)) %>%
  addLegend("bottomleft", 
            pal = pal,
            values = ~meas_value,
            title = "Measured Value (mg/kg)",
            opacity = 1) %>%
  addScaleBar(position = c("bottomright")) %>%
  addLayersControl(baseGroups = c("Open Street Map", "Esri World Street Map", "Esri World Imagery"), 
                   position = "topleft")
```

Column {data-width=100}
-------------------------------------

### Filters

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE}
filter_select(id = "composite_type", label = "Sample Type", sharedData = s_df, group = ~composite_type, allLevels = F, multiple = T)
```
````